# Dropdown with multiple values

Tags: dropdown

I have a configuration page where in there is a field for associating the IP address. IP address will be in huge number. Can some one suggest me what is the best practices to get this done? A dropdown? or some thing else?

Comment: You have a dropdown that has a lot of values (IP addresses) or do you want more than one value to be selected at once.

Comment: It is single selection. Only thing is there are multiple values in in the dropdown. User might find difficult to select the value if it is in 60th one.

Comment: IPs are generally not user friendly. A good approach would be showing server names (which are more remember-able) instead or along with.

Comment: I strongly agree.. But value (IP Address) which i am getting it from some other source which cannot be changed.

Comment: Is each IP address listed separately? Is there any way to group associated IP addresses together?

Comment: We are not listing IP address which is already associated.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using datalist on an input, [checkout on w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

In a project i am working on we use a smart dropdown field (like google actualty) when you type it reads throug an an array in the background and shows only the maching ip adresses.

We use a joker (*) to start at the end of an ip.

0025 wil show all ip's starting with 0025,

*0025 the one's ending with 0025

The control is fairly easy to develop yourself, and there are already enough examples to find

Comment: That a good one. But unfortunately there is a limitation in our application by using ajax dropdown:(  People say for every input there will be a hit to database...

Comment: Thats a fact, but i would suggest to download all the ip's and store it in a local array once, and then you have to do only one database call

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply:) Values which i am getting through an API. So it should be dynamic. IP's will be created in other place and it will be displayed in our application through an API. Downloading and keeping it will not help:(